# How to change behavior from cyclic windows toggling to the latest windows toggling on solaris

Tags: solaris, alt-tab

In solaris OS, when pressing alt-tab, it cycles the opened windows.

Can I change the behavior to toggle the lastest opened  windows as the M$ OS does.

That is, how can I toggle between the two most often used windows with just one alt-tab click instead of toggling all the opened windows every time.

Comment: What version of Solaris? Using what desktop environment?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to switch back to the previous window with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.